# XSS using ajax and json

Tags: javascript, xss

Suppose I have a third party API from which I receive ajax replies, which contain URLs of some pictures and which are used in only two ways: as an argument for `JSON.parse` function and as a source for `<img>` tag. Is this secure and can I be sure no XSS is possible in this situation, even if I don't trust the server providing mentioned API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.parse` is safe, but if you show images in your page for example like this:

```
var o = JSON.parse(reply)
var i = "<img src='" + o.path +'>"
someElement.innerHTML = i
```

then XSS can be done for example like this:

```
{"path" : "aaa.jpg' onload='alert(1)"}
```

To avoid that it would be enough to create image element and set its attributes via js:

```
var i = document.createElement('img')
i.src = o.path
someElement.innerHTML = ''
someElement.appendChild(img)
```

Then it would be totally safe.